# Unable to reference BuildConfig in app gradle file - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am experimenting with basic `gradle` functionality. I am trying to print the product flavor that is currently being built. My gradle build file looks like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 34
        versionName "0.9.14.20180718"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable false
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true   //for optimization.
            shrinkResources true
            multiDexEnabled true

            logger.debug("Hello world.")
            logger.debug("Build flavor being used: " + BuildConfig.FLAVOR)

            //check for build flavour.
            /*if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.contentEquals("managed")) {
                logger.debug("Managed flavour being used here.")
            } else if(BuildConfig.FLAVOR.contentEquals("debugFlavor")) {
                logger.debug("Debug flavor being used.")
            }*/

            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        managed {
            applicationId 'com.test.testing'
        }
        debugFlavor {
            applicationId 'com.test.testdebug
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to change the Gradle file, I get the following error on sync:

```
Error:(30, 0) Could not get unknown property 'BuildConfig' for BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.
<a href="openFile:I:\work\workspace\test\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

I am not sure what the error is. I checked the `BuildConfig.java` file in the project repository and they exist and look just fine.

Comment: may be this site can be helpfull
https://androiddevsimplified.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/gradle-power-android-product-flavours-and-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

> logger.debug("Build flavor being used: " + BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
>
> I am not sure what the error is. I checked the `BuildConfig.java` file
>   in the project repository and they exist and look just fine.

This line is technically wrong, `BuildConfig.java` is a file **generated by gradle build tool**, this file can be used only for your Java/Kotlin s**ource code**, but not for any of your `build.gradle` gradle script files.

Inside gradle script, the correct way for printing out **build flavor** is as below:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        println "flavor.name: " + flavor.name
    }
}
```

If you want to print out **build variants**, it can be done as below:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    println "variant.name: " + variant.name
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. How do I invoke certain tasks **only** when a certain flavor name is built?

Comment: Not exactly sure about your question, do you mean that if you only want to build, for example, app-light-free.apk, what will be the command? Then you can use ‘assembleLiteFree’. The convention is assemble{Flavor}{BuildType} with the first letter of flavor and build type be capitalized.

Comment: No. I mean that I want to include minified versions of js files **only** when the `managed` flavor of buildType `release` is built. Is that possible?

Comment: Each build variant can has its own source sets and resources, you can add your js files into the respective resource or source directory

Answer (score 0):

as [developer.andorid](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) states
you should specify each flavor dimension explicitly:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    demo {
        // Assigns this product flavor to the "version" flavor dimension.
        // This property is optional if you are using only one dimension.
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
        versionNameSuffix "-demo"
    }
    full {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".full"
        versionNameSuffix "-full"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. how does that help with the issue? The error says "BuildConfig" could not be found.

Comment: product flavors are part of BuildConfigs.
I guess if you don't set the dimension it won't be able to create the BuildConfig class.
did you try it?